# Why is redux-sessionstorage not updating my node's attributes when restoring state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, session-storage

I use redux-sessionstorage to store a subset of my app's state to session storage. Part of that state indicates whether certain panels in the UI are expanded or collapsed (visible or hidden).

I have a sample app reproducing exactly this: https://github.com/shawninder/sessionstorage-bug

See the readme for complete reproduction steps.

Also hosted online [here](https://sessionstorage-bug-366v58v29.now.sh/) (give it a moment to unfreeze)

The problem happens when I reload the page. redux-sessionstorage correctly restores the previous state from sessionstorage and triggers a render, yet the style attribute I'm using to do the hiding and showing is not updated.

In other words, this works as expected:

```
<p>showNotice: {props.app.showNotice ? 'true' : 'false'}</p>
```

I can see `showNotice: false` on page load, but it's then immediately replaced by `showNotice: true` when redux-sessionstorage restores the saved state.

But the following doesn't work:

```
<div
  className='notice'
  style={{
    opacity: props.app.showNotice ? 1 : 0,
    transform: props.app.showNotice ? 'translateX(0)' : 'translateX(-100%)'
  }}
>
  Notice!
</div>
```

The page loads with the notice hidden (as expected), but it doesn't get shown when redux-sessionstorage restores the state. In fact, it doesn't show until I click the toggle button twice, the first time to set `showNotice` back to `false`, and then a second time to set it to `true` and show the `<div>`.

Why is redux-sessionstorage not updating the `style` attribute here, and how do people generally handle this?

Comment: have a look here.. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11128 it seems like maybe a react version difference between server and client?

Comment: It's the same code running client side and server side, so I don't see how there could possibly be a version mismatch. I've seen a lot about this issue elsewhere, but I'm having trouble applying the other solutions to my case since I'm not doing the dispatch, redux-sessionstorage is... I was hoping that adding the session-storage tag here would help me find other people with the same specific problem...

Comment: @Shawn I edited my answer with a better explanation on why the code was failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lecstor pointed to the right thread about this issue.

This is a thing with Server Side Rendering (SSR). The workaround Dan Abramov described on this [comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8017#issuecomment-256351955) solved the issue.

You're using Next.js for SSR. When running your project on `dev` mode, you can see the following error message on Chrome console, after pressing Toggle to true and reloading:

`Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "false" Client: "true"`

Since Next doesn't know anything about the saved state on the client side, it always returns `app.showNotice` to `false`. You can also check the returned content for `GET localhost` on Chrome Network Tab.

Apparently `Next.js` tries to merge the content returned from the server and the one rendered locally, but fails to merge the style. Apparently, it's an expected behaviour on Next and also on React 16 SSR, that you can overcome by triggering a second `render()` or doing the implementation below.

```js
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showNotice: false };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ showNotice: this.props.app.showNotice });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({ showNotice: props.app.showNotice });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>showNotice: {this.state.showNotice ? 'true' : 'false'}</p>
        <button onClick={(event) => {
          this.props.dispatch({ type: 'App:toggleNotice' })
        }}>toggle</button>
        <div
          className='notice'
          style={{
            opacity: this.state.showNotice ? 1 : 0,
            transform: this.state.showNotice ? 'translateX(0)' : 'translateX(-100%)'
          }}
        >
          Notice!
        </div>
        <style jsx>{`
          .notice {
            width: 100px;
            transition-property: opacity, transform;
            transition-duration: 0.4s;
          }
        `}</style>
      </div>
    )
  }  
}
```